# Maximum of a function outcome of implicit function theorem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove the next:

If the point $(a, b)$ satisfies the equation $F(x, y) = xy − \log\frac{x}{y} = 0, (x, y > 0),$
then there exists a $C^1$ function $y = f(x)$ which passes through this point and is unique in its neighborhood. Furthermore, there is one point $(a, b)$ such that the corresponding function
$y = f(x)$ has a maximum at $a.$

$F$ is a function of class $C^1$ in $(0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$ because is sum of functions on such class. By hypothesis, $F(a,b)=0$ and $Det(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}(a,b))\neq 0.$ Then Implicit Function Theorem ensures that there is a function f of class $C^1$ defined on a neigborhood of $a$ such that $F(x,f(x)) = 0$ in such neigborhood and $b=f(a).$

To prove uniqueness is enough to consider $F(x, f(x))=0=F(x, g(x))$ in such neigborhood and check the cases when $f\neq g.$

I have problems proving that $f$ has a maximum; I have tried to use implicit differentiation and equals to zero to get a critic point but I do not find something useful.

Any kind of help is thanked in advanced.

Comment: Your first paragraph omits to say that the function $f$ satisfies $F(x,f(x))=0$, so it's very confusing until we get to the second paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implicit differentiation will give you
$$f'(x) = \frac{\frac1x-y}{\frac1y+x},$$
and so we'll have a critical point at $(a,b)$ precisely when $\dfrac1a-b = 0$, i.e., when $ab=1$. But then substituting into $F(a,b)=0$ gives $\log a = 1/2$, or $a=e^{1/2}$ and $b=e^{-1/2}$.
(I did not stop to check that $a$ is a local maximum of $f$.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That was helpful.